# how can i combine two mysql query to get one single result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two mysql query as below

```
SELECT cv_requirement,cv_target,cv_target_date_for 
FROM `cv_target` 
where cv_target_date_for between '2014-02-20' and '2014-02-27' and cv_recruiter='44'

AND

select count(candidate_id)as achi,cv_target_date from candidate
where fk_posted_user_id='44'
and cv_target_date between '2014-02-20' and '2014-02-27'
group by fk_job_id,cv_target_date
```

the first query produce `11 record` and the second one shows `10 record` 
how i can combine this two query to get single query result to show `11 record with 10 values and 1 null value`

i have tried this but showing only `10 record not null record`

```
SELECT cv_requirement,cv_target,cv_target_date_for,count(candidate_id) achi, cv_target_date
FROM `cv_target` a
left join candidate b 
on a.cv_requirement=b.fk_job_id and a.cv_target_date_for=b.cv_target_date
where cv_target_date_for between '2014-02-20' and '2014-02-27' and cv_recruiter='44'
group by cv_requirement,cv_target

query one
    fk_job_id   achi    cv_target_date Ascending
    188         1       2014-02-20
    220         1       2014-02-20
    220         1       2014-02-21
    221         5       2014-02-21
    224         1       2014-02-22
    224         2       2014-02-24
    224         2       2014-02-25
    222         1       2014-02-25
    222         3       2014-02-26
    224         1       2014-02-27


query two

cv_requirement  cv_target   cv_target_date_for
188             2           2014-02-20
220             2           2014-02-21
221             2           2014-02-21
224             3           2014-02-22
220             1           2014-02-22
224             2           2014-02-24
222             1           2014-02-24
224             4           2014-02-25
222             4           2014-02-25
222             3           2014-02-26
224             3           2014-02-27


i want this out put

cv_requirement  cv_target   cv_target_date_for  achi
188             2           2014-02-20          1
220             2           2014-02-21          1
221             2           2014-02-21          5
224             3           2014-02-22          1
220             1           2014-02-22          0
224             2           2014-02-24          2
222             1           2014-02-24          0
224             4           2014-02-25          2
222             4           2014-02-25          1
222             3           2014-02-26          3
224             3           2014-02-27          1
```

pls provide some help .

Comment: You can use union . See here stackoverflow.com/questions/5331808/how-do-i-combine-the-results-of-two-queries-with-ordering

Comment: @avisheks i have added the two table query output and the resultant out put that i want pls help

Comment: make it RIGHT OUTER JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 SELECT cv_requirement,cv_target,cv_target_date_for, achi
  FROM (SELECT cv_requirement,cv_target,cv_target_date_for 
   FROM `cv_target` 
   where cv_target_date_for between '2014-02-20' and '2014-02-27' and cv_recruiter='44') a

   left outer  join
    (
    select count(candidate_id)as achi,cv_target_date from candidate
  where fk_posted_user_id='44'
  and cv_target_date between '2014-02-20' and '2014-02-27'
  group by fk_job_id,cv_target_date) b

  on a.cv_requirement=b.fk_job_id and a.cv_target_date_for=b.cv_target_date
```

Comment: i am getting the same result as i was getting from my query.

Comment: i have updated the question and the result that i want

Answer (score 1):

The grouping is eliminating your 11th record. You should perform the `group by` in an inner query, and only then join the two:

```
SELECT          cv_requirement, cv_target, cv_target_date_for, achi
FROM            cv_target a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT   COUNT(candidate_id) AS achi, cv_target_date 
                 FROM     candidate
                 GROUP BY fk_job_id,cv_target_date) 
ON              a.cv_requirement = b.fk_job_id AND 
                a.cv_target_date_for = b.cv_target_date
WHERE           cv_target_date_for BETWEEN '2014-02-20' AND '2014-02-27' AND 
                cv_recruiter = '44'
```